# Not able to create HBase schema from java client

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to create HBase schema from java client but it is throwing following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:156)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:327)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:167)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:162)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:796)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:408)
```

The same is working with HBase shell. Following is my code snippet:

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
HTableDescriptor table =new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("xyz"));
table.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("default"));
admin.createTable(table);
admin.close();
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: connection is not configured properly

Comment: What should i add in connection?

Answer (score 0):

You should add zookeeper (cluster) address in your configuration

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","your.zookeeper.address")
```